# SharePoint 2013: Email approval if site or documents shared to "everyone"?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow

Is there a way to automatically send an email approval to the site administrators if the site or a document is shared to everyone?

Maybe by using OOTB workflows or SharePoint Desgigner?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workflow trigger for "On permissions Change" do xyz.  The only triggers are related to list items or documents.  I'm sure that there is away to do this with a custom event receiver or something like that, but Workflow will not meet your needs in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Josh McClanahan.

By custom event receiver, do you mean like a PowerShell script ?

Answer (score 0):

Event receiver is not a powershell script, it is a custom solution for handling certain actions in SharePoint. You will need development skills to write codes in VS to do it.

> By creating event receivers, you can respond when a user interacts
> with SharePoint items such as lists or list items. For example, the
> code in an event receiver can be triggered when a user changes the
> calendar or deletes a name from a contacts list.

[How to: Create an event receiver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-create-an-event-receiver?view=vs-2019)

For sharing, if a user who does not have the permission to manage permission, by default, not a site collection admin, or someone with Full control, there will be access requests sent to site admins. They can accept or decline the request.

Reference for you: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/manage-access-request-settings-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jerry_MSFT

Do you think it's possible with a PowerShell script ?

Comment: @Mapow, I don't think it can be done with a script.

Comment: Is it because there is no command that match the idea ?

Comment: @Mapow, powershell cmdlet is not a tool to construct actions when certain events happened. It does not have things like the workflow triggers.

Comment: Agreed, but I have a script that trigger a list of all sites and subsites where there is "Everyone".
So maybe I can edit a script to send an email to administrators like that ?